# SQL query works in SQLite but not in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have following query that works in SQLite but not in MySQL

```
select t.range as [range], count(*) as frequency                        
  from (select case
                 when x.sum between 0.5 and 100 then '0.5 - 100'                
                 when x.sum between 100.5 and 1000 then '100.5 - 1000'        
                 when x.sum between 1000.5 and 2000 then '1000.5 - 2000'
               end as range                                                  
        from (select l.id, sum(i.price) sum                                     
                from lists l
                  join items i                                                  
                    on i.list_id = l.id                                         
                  join line_items li                                            
                    on li.item_id = i.id and li.reversal_id is null             
              group by l.id) x ) t                                             
group by t.range;
```

Running MySQL it gives following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '[range], count(*) as frequency
from (select case
               when x.sum b' at line 1
```

Comment: remove brackets

Comment: @splash58 actually there are 2 errors, the brackets you mentioned and as Gordon Linoff pointed out the usage of the reserved word range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to fix.  MySQL does not recognize square braces as escape characters.  You can use backticks or double quotes:

```
select t.`range` as `range`, count(*) as frequency
```

`range` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so you need to escape the identifier throughout the query.

Or just use another name, such as `sum_range` that does not need to be escaped.

You can simplify the query to:

```
select (case when x.sum between 0.5 and 100 then '0.5 - 100'                
             when x.sum between 100.5 and 1000 then '100.5 - 1000'        
             when x.sum between 1000.5 and 2000 then '1000.5 - 2000'
        end) as sum_range,
       count(*) as frequency                                                 
from (select l.id, sum(i.price) sum                                     
      from lists l join
           items i                                                  
           on i.list_id = l.id join                                        
           line_items li                                            
           on li.item_id = i.id and li.reversal_id is null             
      group by l.id
     ) x
group by sum_range;
```

Comment: fast, eloquent and very helpful - Thank you!